# axios receives array_filter result as an object instead of array

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios, array-filter

I have a laravel API called get_product_list, it receives some parameters and then uses php built-in function array_filter to filter all products and returns them at the end.It's something like the following code.

```
public function get_product_list(Request $request)
{
    //validations
    //some code

    $all_products = NULL ;

    //getting all products in an array
    $all_products = $this->get_all_products();

    //applying filters
    $all_products = array_filter($all_products, function($product) use($request){
        $category_flag = true;
        if($request->filled('category_id')){
            $category_flag = ( $request->category_id == $product['main']->category_id);
        }
        return $category_flag;
    });

    return response()->json([
        'status' => TRUE,
        'products' => $all_products
    ],200);

}
```

I call this API in axios like this

```
axios.post('/get_product_list', {
               category_id:2,
           })
           .then(function (response) {
                    self.products = response.data.products;
           });
```

The issue is when I don't pass category_id to the API I receive an array, but when I pass it to the API I receive an object instead of an array.

what's wrong with my code?

I don't want to convert the received object to an array in axios, I want the API to give me the array.

Comment: Can you show the code for your `get_all_products` method?

Comment: it returns an array for sure! @RossWilson

Comment: Oh, ok. Cool. I kinda figured it would be returning an array otherwise `array_filter` would throw an error. That wasn't the reason I asked if I could see the code for it. At the end of the day, unless I know what the exact value of `$all_products` I can't attempt to replicate the issue and ultimately try and debug it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with `array_filter()` is that it maintains keys.

For example, if you have an array with 5 items and filter out indexes 0 and 2, you end up with

```php
[
  1 => ...,
  3 => ...,
  4 => ...
]
```

`json_encode()` will create a JSON **object** in this case because it doesn't see a flat array.

The simple solution is to re-index the array with [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-values.php), eg

```php
return response()->json([
    'status' => TRUE,
    'products' => array_values($all_products)
], 200);
```

Comment: yes your answer is complete. I solved the problem this way $products = [];  foreach($all_products as $product){
           $products[] = $product;
       }
to re-index the array but array_values() seems much better.